# Getting the last record of a user in a table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join

A stored procedure I am working on from a previous developer is joining many tables together to return one record of a "participant" for a particular event. One table in question may not have the information for that event, however I still need to return certain data of that participants LAST entry into that stored procedure. There is a datalastmodified column, but that is not one of the fields being return. How do I return the data in question within the stored procedure of the last entry?

Here is a sample; if a user enters a participant that is not affiliated with the current event it needs to look in the EventAffiliation table for the last entry of that participant:

table ParticipantGenInfo

```
userid,
eventid,
firstname,
lastname,
```

table EventAffiliation

```
userid,
eventid,
field,
degree,
degreeyear,
datelastmodified
```

stored procedure example (left join is actual code)

```
select
     pgi.userid,
     pgi.firstname,
     pgi.lastname,
     ea.field,
     ea.degree,
     ea.degreeyear
from ParticipantGenInfo pgi
left join EventAffiliation ea
     on pgi.userid = ea.userid and pgi.eventid = ea.eventid
where pgi.eventid = 'xxxxx'
```

Comment: A code / tables involved example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too vague to answer, but you will want to have a query something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... ORDER BY DataLastModified DESC
```